# angular2 set service property in route resolve

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

So i have a relatively large application with lazy-loaded feature modules, and within those modules a series of components that work on a particular data structure, e.g.:

`/thing/123/profile
/thing/123/subscriptions
/thing/123/history`

these components use a resolve guard to ensure that the data id (`123`) referenced in the url loads the appropriate data structure into the governing `thing` service.  the resolve guard uses this service data preferentially to avoid looking the data up repetitively on sibling route navigation, and the components (`profile`,`subscriptions`,`history`) simply use `thing` from the service, remaining ignorant of the resolve guard's efforts to ensure that the data has been loaded.  If the data is loaded in the service, resolve uses that, and if not, it looks it up during route resolution.

sounds great, right?  well somewhere around angular 2.0.X something, the resolve guard stopped updating the service with the data during route resolution.

if i use `ActivatedRoute.data.forEach()` in the individual components' `OnInit`, i can see that the resolve guard did indeed load the data, and i can re-map it back to the service at this time, however i'm trying to avoid re-implementing a route data check on each child component, especially since in most cases (sibling navigation) the data is already set on the service.  The resolve guard is an observable from the `thing` service in question which sets its own data member.  within the service when the observable runs, the value is set appropriately.  it resolves appropriately into route data.  yet this data has disappeared from the service by the time the route loads...

*this is only an issue when loading the full url, e.g. a refresh on the final route, where the resolve has to load the data fresh -- if it's in the service before navigating to the route, it's fine.*

i can put together a plunkr with a simple example later, don't have time to pare it down from the actual app right now, but just wondered if anyone has seen this behavior or knows the reason why this may happen (some scoping issue with the service injected in the base app for purposes of route resolution but in the feature module once the route's loaded, etc) or if this is unexpected behavior?

tl;dr - why does my service properly set a property on itself during route resolution, but that property is unset once the route actually loads?  this is not unique to one feature module, but consistent across my whole app, destroying my ability to abstract route parameter resolution into a service leaving components ignorant of the lookup.  thanks in advance!

Comment: Could it have something to do with where you provide the service? Is it possibly being re-initialized somewhere after the resolved route data is first set to it?

Comment: @Fredrik -- that's a good thought, i'll trace the service constructor and see if it's being recreated at some point, although i don't see why it would be - it's only provided once, by the feature module it serves

Answer (score 1):

i guess i didn't look hard enough.  known issue with router @^3.2.0 where it instantiates providers twice.  solution is to downgrade router temporarily until fixed.

kudos to @Fredrik Lundin for suggesting recreated service, the service was indeed being recreated after the route had been resolved.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12869